# HTML5 Web SQL value for foreign key

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html, sqlite

I am using HTML5 Web SQL and Javascript to set up my tables. I have two tables: games & frames. I need to pull the last record (most recent) id from the games table and use it as a foreign key in the frames table.

```
 function createGame (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, created unique, alley, date DATETIME, weight)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO games(created, alley, date, weight) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', [created, alley, date, weight]);
           }
```

My created, alley, date, and weight values are being defined outside of the function above.

```
function createFrame (tx) {
                tx.executeSql("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frames(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, frame, pins, comments, FOREIGN KEY (gameID) REFERENCES games(id))');
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO frames(frame, pins, comments, gameID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [frame, pins, comments, gameID]);
           }
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the value for the last (most recent) record's id in the games table and use it for the foreign key in the frames table.

Defining it as a variable like below has given me no luck:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT LAST(id) FROM games', [], function(transaction,output) {
                var gameID = output.id;
                console.log(output);
            });
          });
```

Could someone tell me the best way to get the value of the last id in the games table to use it as a foreign key for the frames table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "WebSQL" isn't a thing any more. It's dead, you shouldn't be writing new software which uses it. Consider IndexedDB as an alternative.

Comment: @meagar Many HTML5 frameworks for mobile devices use WebSQL as their only database mechanism.

Comment: @CL. This doesn't appear to be the case in this question. There is no framework mentioned, only hand-rolled WebSQL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the largest value, use [max](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#maxggunc):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM games
```

To get the frames belonging to that game, search for the value returned by that query, or just compute it directly with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM frames WHERE gameID = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM games)
```

Answer (score 0):

first if you are going to have a last game... don't try to query the last game every frame

```
      SELECT id FROM games ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

this will return the last game's id.

then save results.row.id in localstorage so you can easily access it with out the taxation of having to keep doing multiple table queries (phones have limited memory) .   and use it as a variable for your frames.

or if you prefer to do do it as a sub query

```
SELECT * FROM frames WHERE gameID = (SELECT id FROM games ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
```